# Getting values in double array from index. Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a collection view made up of 4 sections.

Each section is an array of strings, like this:

```
var picList: [String] = ["Bird", "Cat", "Cow", "Dog", "Duck", "Elephant", "Fish", "Giraffe", "Lion", "Mouse", "Sheep", "Snake" ]

var vehiclesList: [String] = ["Airplane", "Ambulance", "Boat", "Bus", "Car", "Fire_Engine", "Helicopter", "Motorcycle", "Tank", "Tractor", "Train", "Truck" ]

var fruitsList: [String] = ["Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Mango", "Orange", "Peach", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Watermelon" ]

var bodyPartsList: [String] = ["Arm", "Ear", "Eye", "Face", "Feet", "Hand", "Hair", "Legs", "Mouth", "Nose" ]
```

I created a UITapGestureRecognizer for the cell, that when I click on the cell, I get the index.

Here is the tapMethod

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap")

        if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: sender.location(in: self.collectionView)) {

            let cell = collectionView?.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PicViewCell

            print("index path: + \(indexPath)")


        } else {
            print("")
        }


    }
```

Now the index prints like this [0,0] (if I press on the first item, ie bird). [2,4] if I press on the 4th item in the 2nd secion (ie mango). But I don't know how to translate the index, to get the corresponding string value. I mean something like this:

var itemName: String = [2,4] (and itemName would be mango)

I'm new to swift, so any help would be great.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Actually `[2,4]` is the 5th item in the 3rd section ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an array of arrays, aka a 2D array - `[[String]]`.

```
var array = [picList, vehicleList, fruitsList, bodyPartsList]
```

Then, you can access this with 2 indices like this:

```
var itemName = array[2][4]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: @ios234975 if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a two dimensional array, and add there your lists, indexpath.section will be the index of list and indexpath.item will be the index in thst list

Comment: Thanks. Great, together with Sweeper's answer